# Regex for allowing alphanumeric, special characters and space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching for a regular expression for allowing alphanumeric characters, special characters (-_'àâçèéêîôùûÀÈÙÇÉ), or spaces in the middle in JavaScript. I tried Googling but wasn't able to find that.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
([\d\w\-'àâçèéêîôùûÀÈÙÇÉ])([\d\w\-' àâçèéêîôùûÀÈÙÇÉ][\d\w\-'àâçèéêîôùûÀÈÙÇÉ]+)*
```

Check this expression on https://regexr.com/